# Why showing error in while loops and if statement

Tags: python-3.x, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Today I was writing a while loop code in python3 here is the code:

```
#Simulate supermarket billing process
while True:
    total=0
    repeat="y"
    Noc=input("Enter customer's name here:")
    while repeat=="y":
        print("1. Keep adding.")
        print("2. Print the bill amount.")
        choice=int(input("Enter your choice(1 or 2):")
        if choice==1 or choice==2:
            if choice==1:
               itemqty=int(input("Etner item quantity here:"))
               itemamt=float(input("Enter item price Here:"))
               total=total+itemqty*itemamt
            elif choice==2:
                 print("The total amount is:",total)
                 repeat=input("Do you want to enter more items?(Y/y/N/n)")
        else:
            print("Incorrect choice...Enter again")
#print a bill
print("Name:"," ",Noc,)
print("Total Amount:"," ", total)
print("-----**Thanks for Shopping**-----")
mp=input("Want to go to next person?(Y/y/N/n)")
if mp="N" or mp="n":
   break
```

And this error is coming

```
File "/home/agupta/Documents/anant/codingPlayground/learnPython/Chapter 4/hi.py", line 10
    if choice==1 or choice==2:
                             ^
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

Please could someone tell what is the error?

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line above the error, for the `int()` function. This happens a lot with debugging — the compiler doesn't realize there is an error until just *after* the erroneous line has occurred.

Comment: by the way, i don't think you'll ever print the Name and Total Amount lines because of the outermost `while` loop... You need a `break` of some kind in there.

Answer (score 0):

As @beroe suggest:

```
choice=int(input("Enter your choice(1 or 2):"))
```

One more hint: after solving this issue, you can start improving this piece of code in this way too

```
choice=int(input("Enter your choice(1 or 2):")

if choice==1:
   itemqty=int(input("Etner item quantity here:"))
   itemamt=float(input("Enter item price Here:"))
   total=total+itemqty*itemamt
elif choice==2:
    print("The total amount is:",total)
    repeat=input("Do you want to enter more items?(Y/y/N/n)")
else:
    print("Incorrect choice...Enter again")
```